# Relocating Physical Node Location

Tags: lightning-network, full-node, nodes

Are you able to relocate your node's physical location (i.e., move from Oregon to New York) and keep all the channels you've established intact?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Channels are associated with a `node_id`, which is just the public key of the node. The association of a `node_id` to an IP address (or Onion address) is dynamic and is broadcast over the P2P gossip network when your node connects to another. It only takes a few minutes after reconnection for your new IP to propagate through the entire network.

However, you should reconnect as timely as possible after turning your node offline. If parties you have open channels with find you unresponsive for so long, they may attempt to unilaterally close the channels they have open with you. If they also believe you are offline and not monitoring the channels, they may attempt to broadcast an expired channel state to take more of the balance than they currently have in the channel.

Comment: Just to add: I already did it without problems